# How to fix this : AttributeError: module 'plotly' has no attribute 'graph_objs'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly, data-visualization, jupyter

I'm new to plotly, trying to create a first plot with plotly in jupyter lab. But it says that the plotly module has no attribute named graph_objs.

I have installed and uninstalled plotly and cufflinks several times but this error does not go away. 
I have tried importing plotly, plotly.plotly or other modules from plotly.

Before this there was another error: No module named 'Retrying'. I solved that by uninstalling and installing the 'Retrying' module.

One more piece of info:
It worked partially fine before I did this: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py#jupyterlab-support-python-35

`import plotly as py`

This is the error:

```
     28 from __future__ import absolute_import
     29 
---> 30 from plotly import (
     31     graph_objs,
     32     tools,
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/io/_utils.py in <module>
      2 
      3 import plotly
----> 4 import plotly.graph_objs as go
      5 
      6 

AttributeError: module 'plotly' has no attribute 'graph_objs'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Plotly** has been updated. Maybe that is because you are facing error, in their latest release, it's been changed to `graph_objects`. So try this:

```
from plotly import graph_objects
```

Make sure, you installed `plotly` of latest version.

Check this for reference : https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Can you please reproduce your code, so that I can test it properly ?

Comment: `graph_objects` actually re-exports `graph_objs` and the latter has not been removed in version 4.

Comment: @amrs-tech That's it for the code. It doesn't even import plotly into jupyter lab.

If it helps, I imported plotly in jupyter notebook and it works fine.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know far more than this. Maybe try installing inside jupyter the plotly through this : `!pip install plotly` in the first cell to run plotly installation inside jupyter.